# VLOOKUP not finding value in array

Tags: excel, rounding, vlookup, ceil

I used `VLOOKUP` function to find a value in an array but some of the values gave #N/A answer despite of available in array.

[image]

To round up the numbers, I used `CEILING` function but interesting point is in some values, it did not work.

I checked the type of value if it is number or not.

Also, I used `ROUNDUP` function but did not work.

Also, I tried `INDEX`/`MATCH` combination and again did not work.

In the example that I gave in the link, when I type between 15.00 - 15.20, it gives error but trying other values, it works.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` using the return values of `CEILING`. If you use:

`=VLOOKUP(ROUND(CEILING(F4,0.1),1),A:B,2,FALSE)`

then it works as expected.

If we look at this with VBA then we see what happens. To blame should be really `CEILING` and `ROUNDUP`. See example:

```
Sub testCeilingAndRoundup()

 Dim v As Double, test As Boolean, diff As Double

 v = [CEILING(15.1,0.1)] '15.1
 test = (v = 15.1) 'FALSE
 diff = 15.1 - v '-1.776...E-15

 v = [ROUNDUP(15.25,1)] '15.3
 test = (v = 15.3) 'FALSE
 diff = 15.3 - v '1.776...E-15

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've run into an Excel bug.

Applying `CEILING` to the number 15.1 should return the exact same result (15.1) regardless of whether the significance is 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc.

And indeed it does, according to Excel: when asked if they're equal, the answer is always `TRUE`.

But looking up these mathematically equal numbers in the look-up table gives different results.

[image]

This has to be a bug.

<strike>Instead of `CEILING(F4,0.1)`, I suggest you use `ROUNDUP(F4,1)` which appears to be bug-free.</strike> Nope, `ROUNDUP` is buggy as well. [Axel Richter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252174/119775) suggests wrapping `CEILING` in a `ROUND` and this does appear to make the problem go away. You can also convert to string and back to number:

```
VALUE(TEXT(ROUNDUP(F4,1),"0.0"))
```

so you'd have

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(TEXT(ROUNDUP(F4,1),"0.0")),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CEILING` function should be more precise if you want to find a match for *15.10*

Change it to `CEILING(F4,0.01)` and it will works :)

Comment: This fails if the input is e.g. 15.09. The intent is clearly to round this up to 15.10 and return 95, but your formula gives an error.

Comment: Also, I don't understand *why* `CEILING(15.10,0.1)` and `CEILING(15.10,0.01)` would behave differently (though testing shows that they do). Both should in principle return the exact same number i.e. 15.1. So I don't understand why you suggested this answer!

Comment: `CEILING(15.10, 0.1)` and `CEILING(15.10, 0,01)` are the same. There is no difference.