# Using Rounded Values as Inputs to VLOOKUP causing #N/A return

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following values in excel (A1 etc are cell references):

```
A1 = 0.0625 'User Input
A2 = ROUNDDOWN(A1,2) = 0.06 
A3 = ROUNDUP(A1,2) = 0.07
```

I then use the values of A2 and A3 in VLOOKUP calls:

```
B2 = IF(A2>0.3,"Out of Range",VLOOKUP(A2,data!$A$42:$B$71,2,FALSE))
B3 = IF(A3>0.3,"Out of Range",VLOOKUP(A3,data!$A$42:$B$71,2,FALSE))
```

B2 populates correctly. B3 returns `#N/A`

The range I am looking in contains the following data:

[image]

All of the data required is available, the sheet does not seem to be able to get the value for 0.07. Can anybody see why? It seems to work for all other values I have tried so far.

**KEY INFO**
If I erase `A3 = ROUNDUP(A1,2)` and just type `0.07` into the cell `A3`, it works perfectly fine. So I'm curious about what ROUNDUP is doing, as it seemingly causes VLOOKUP to fall over.

I have tried nesting the ROUNDUP function into my VLOOKUP equation, but I get the same result.

Comment: As included in the question, if I type 0.07 as a hard value, VLOOKUP works. It seems to be directly related to ROUNDUP. A colleague asked me this, and I fixed it by giving them a routine for linear interpolation, however I am still curious as to why this is broken.

Comment: You are right! Crazy.

Comment: @Kanak Tell me about it. Seems like a bug, but I'd love to know more.

Comment: Just did a test myself and had the same problem. I found that this resolved the problem `=INT(100*ROUNDUP(A1,2))/100` which might suggest it's related to the floating point storage of decimals. But why ROUNDUP works is a mystery!

Comment: I may be wrong, but Excel's low level may actually deal with binary numbers. And `0.07` is `0.00010001111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001...` which implies a truncation so as to be written finitely. Excel shows you `0.07`, but it may actually have something like `0.07000001` in "mind". Hence the bug you get. `ROUND(ROUNDUP(A1, 2), 2)` does the job as well.

Comment: @SJR Interesting, that works for me too. Seems like something that should not be happening with such an established piece of software though, doesn't it... I also figured that although the cell displays 0.07 in cell A3, it cannot be searching for that when VLOOKUP is called, so I was hoping someone here would be able to explain how/why this is.

Comment: Read this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/ but as I say I don't understand why ROUNDDOWN works.

Comment: This link might be better https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel

Comment: @Kanak - what you say makes sense. I tried a few examples and only UP had problems which made me wonder if something else was going on though.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251567/vlookup-not-finding-value-in-array/29252174#29252174

Comment: I have noticed that if I force Excel to 'Set Precision as Displayed' (in File>Options>Advanced) then everything works fine, so it seems this is related to the storage of the values within excel itself. However, this is far from ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Axel Richter and @SJR in the comments, it would seem that this bug is related to the manner in which Excel stores values following rounding. See the [answer to this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251567/vlookup-not-finding-value-in-array/29252174#29252174) for a similar example with the Ceiling function.

There appear to be a few workarounds:

**1) Using INT()**

```
=INT(100*ROUNDUP(A1,2))/100
```

Rather than simply using ROUNDUP solves the issue.

**2) Force Excel to Work with Displayed Precision**

```
File > Options > Advanced > Set Precision As Displayed
```

However, this can lead to loss of data, and is not exactly an optimal solution

**3) ROUND your ROUNDUP**

```
ROUND(ROUNDUP(A1, 2), 2)
```

Thanks to @Kanak for this one.

**Other Comments**

In my case using `=CEILING(A1,0.01)` works, but in the aforementioned previous question, CEILING was actually the problem also - so this should not be considered a solution.

Applying @Axel Richter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251567/vlookup-not-finding-value-in-array/29252174#29252174) from before to my question shows that using `ROUNDUP` can lead to a small difference between what is displayed in the cell and the value that Excel is actually storing. In my case, the error in rounding is as follows:

```
 Sub testRoundup()

 Dim v As Double, test As Boolean, diff As Double

 v = [ROUNDUP(0.0625,2)]            '0.07
 test = (v = 0.07)                  'FALSE
 diff = 0.07 - v                    '1.38777878078145E-17

End Sub
```

Another [good resource](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel).

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the given answer:

The IEEE specification of floating point arithmetic is **not** to blame for this problem. Instead it is clearly a bug in implementation of  `CEILING` and  `ROUNDUP`. Rounding should be the **solution** while using floating point numbers and should not be the problem.

Thanks to the fact that `*.xlsx` files are simply ZIP archives, we can simply unzip it and have a look into what is really stored. As an example in `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` we find:

```
<sheetData>
 <row r="1" spans="1:2">
  <c r="A1">
   <f>ROUNDUP(0.0625,2)</f>
   <v>6.9999999999999993E-2</v>
  </c>
  <c r="B1">
   <f>ROUND(ROUNDUP(0.0625,2),2)</f>
   <v>7.0000000000000007E-2</v>
  </c>
 </row>
 <row r="2" spans="1:2">
  <c r="A2">
   <f>CEILING(0.0625,0.01)</f>
   <v>7.0000000000000007E-2</v>
  </c><c r="B2">
   <f>ROUND(CEILING(0.0625,0.01),2)</f>
   <v>7.0000000000000007E-2</v>
  </c>
 </row>
 <row r="3" spans="1:2">
  <c r="A3">
   <f>ROUNDUP(15.25,1)</f>
   <v>15.299999999999999</v>
  </c>
  <c r="B3">
   <f>ROUND(ROUNDUP(15.25,1),1)</f>
   <v>15.3</v>
  </c>
 </row>
 <row r="4" spans="1:2">
  <c r="A4">
   <f>CEILING(15.1,0.1)</f>
   <v>15.100000000000001</v>
  </c>
  <c r="B4">
   <f>ROUND(CEILING(15.1,0.1),1)</f>
   <v>15.1</v>
  </c>
 </row>
</sheetData>
```

As we see here, the claiming: "storing only 15 significant digits of precision"  is not really true. Instead the real numbers in IEEE 754 `double` precision having up to 17 digits of precision are stored. And additionally `ROUNDUP` and `CEILING` sometimes are **not** storing the rounded values. And this is a bug in my opinion as I said. `ROUND` and `ROUNDDOWN` are always storing the rounded values as it should.